Blender Pink Screen On Render
I was trying to render my animation for storyboarding with workbench. Then all of a sudden when I pressed F12 the render screen turned pink.

This is what it looks like

then this is the render result


hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

You have a strip in the Video Sequencer, Blender tries to render this strip, not your scene, so just remove this strip (or, if you want to keep it, go into the Output panel > Post Processing > disable Sequencer).

omg, im such an idiot, anyways thanks man, you just saved my life.

@johnnyherbert.j The stakes are high these days!
